# Devise, looking for a good way to integration test the interaction between two users in a turn based system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, devise, capybara

Stack:  Rails '4.0.4', devise, rSpec, factory_girl,  cappybara + selenium-webdriver, mySQL

I'm stll finding myself a little confused controlling user auth in my tests, but this patchwork from other examples is working for now.  I have a file called `request_helpers.rb` in `/support` that contains:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers

module RequestHelpers
  class Login
    def self.create_logged_in_user
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
        login(user)
        user
    end

    def self.login(user)
      login_as user, scope: :user, run_callbacks: false
    end
  end
end
```

And this is an example of a passing test:

```
require "spec_helper"

feature "Story Management" do

    let( :authorized_user ){ RequestHelpers::Login.create_logged_in_user }

      scenario  "has a valid factory" do
        authorized_user.should be_an_instance_of( User )
      end

      scenario "Can visit root", js:true do
         visit root_path( authorized_user )
         page.should have_content( "Your Stories" )
      end
end
```

My question is,  How can I logout my authorized user, and log in a new authorized user? Every attempt to utilize devise logout method in my request helper hasn't worked.

Here is my attempt at testing this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

module RequestHelpers
  class Login
    def self.create_logged_in_user
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      login(user)
      user
    end
    def self.login(user)
      login_as user, scope: :user, run_callbacks: false
    end
    def self.logout(user)
       logout( user )
    end
  end
end

scenario "Two users can take turns adding 3 chapters each" do
    chapter_string = ValidString.short
    player1 = create(:user)
    player2 = create(:user) 
    RequestHelpers::Login.login(player1)

    visit new_story_path( player1 )
    fill_in "story_title", with: ValidString.short
    fill_in "co_author", with: player2.email
    click_button "Create Story"

    click_link "New Chapter"
    fill_in "chapter_body", with: chapter_string
    click_button "Create Chapter"
    page.should have_content(chapter_string)

    RequestHelpers::Login.logout(player1)

    RequestHelpers::Login.login(player2)

    fill_in "chapter_body", with: chapter_string
    click_button "Create Chapter"
    page.should have_content(chapter_string)
end
```

Failed test text:

```
1) Chapter Management Two users can take turns adding 3 chapters each
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     SystemStackError:
       stack level too deep
     # ./spec/support/request_helpers.rb:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to stop trying to hack around devise here, and just fill in the forms like they suggested in the docs. Logging in and out works fine in this scenario, although slower.

From Devise docs:

> These helpers are not going to work for integration tests driven by Capybara or Webrat. They are meant to be used with functional tests only. Instead, fill in the form or explicitly set the user in session.